# Stata: xtunitroot

Tags: stata, statsmodels

I need to check if inflation is a stationary variable or not. To check this I want to use `xtunitroot` command (in Stata). I first set my cpij(inflatation variable) over a time variable(tv):

```
xtset cpij tv

panel variable:  cpij (unbalanced)
time variable:  tv, 1 to 245, but with gaps
        delta:  1 unit
```

Then I run
`xtunitroot llc cpij`

But I get
*Levin-Lin-Chiu test requires strongly balanced data*

How can I fix this problem?

I have tried

```
xtunitroot fisher cpij, dfuller lags(1)
```

But I get

```
performing unit-root test on first panel using the syntax

dfuller cpij, lags(1) 

returned error code 2000

r(2000);
```

Comment: Do you even have a panel? It seems you only have one series, so you could use dfuller directly. The issue is that your series contains missing values, which apparently the command does not handle.

Comment: This is only one series. There is one missing value, so I checked it on another variable with no missing data, but I received the same error.

Comment: Nothing reproducible here. Please note http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Btw: The test is called Levin–Lin–Chu (Levin–Lin–Chu (2002)), not Levin–Lin–Chiu even if it seems the error message by Stata contains a typo.

Answer (score 2):

My best guess based on what you have given, is that either you are incorrectly specifying your data as panel data when it should be declared time series, or you are incorrectly specifying your panel id in `xtset`.

If you have a single series, (i.e., price index in the United States over time, `tv`), you will want to declare the data to be time series data using `tsset tv` and conduct a unit root test on cpi from here (either Dickey-Fuller or Phillips-Perron, `dfuller` or `pperron`, respectively).

If you indeed do have a panel (i.e., price index across all OECD countries over time), then you will want to declare data to be panel data using `xtset CountryId tv`

The return code r(2000) indicates that there are no observations on which to conduct the test. This is what leads me to suspect one of these two issues. If your cpij variable has no duplicate values, then you cannot test for unit root since within each value of cpij you will only have one time period.

See below for when to use `xtset` vs. `tsset`:

```
tsset t

 +----------+
 |  cpi   t |
 |----------|
 | 1.33   1 |
 | 1.39   2 |
 |  1.4   3 |
 | 1.47   4 |
 | 1.47   5 |
 +----------+

xtset PanelId t

 +--------------------+
 |  cpi   t   PanelId |
 |--------------------|
 | 1.33   1         1 |
 | 1.39   2         1 |
 |  1.4   3         1 |
 | 1.47   4         1 |
 | 1.47   5         1 |
 |--------------------|
 | 1.51   1         2 |
 | 1.52   2         2 |
 | 1.52   3         2 |
 |  1.6   4         2 |
 | 1.61   5         2 |
 +--------------------+
```